# Flutter google places language besides suggestions wrong

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

I'm using google places package.
When I'm searching for a location the results are shown in my default phone language (Spanish).
When I tap on a location the location name is shown in a textfield but always in english. 
How can I change the language?

What I did

```
Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                    context: context,
                    apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
                    mode: Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
                    language: "es",
                    components: [new Component(Component.country, "es")]);
                displayPrediction(p);

Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      // get detail (lat/lng)
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);
      final lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      final lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;
      final locationName = detail.result.name;
      if (detail == null) {
        name = "";
        latitude = 0.0;
        longitude = 0.0;
      } else {
        name = locationName;
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lng;
        searchLocationController.text = locationName;
        getLocation(lat, lng);
        print(locationName);
        print(lat);
        print(lng);
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()); //Dismisses KEyboard
        //Camera position on new target
        mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
              lat,
              lng,
            ),
            zoom: 15,
          ),
        ));
      }
    }
  }
```

the print of locationName is always english

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places

> ## pubspec.yaml
>
> dependencies:   flutter:
>       sdk: flutter   flutter_google_places:

```
const kGoogleApiKey = "API_KEY";

Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                          context: context,
                          apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                          mode: Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
                          language: "es",
                          components: [new Component(Component.country, "es")]);
//to localize the result language apply below code to widget/component

import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

MaterialApp(
 localizationsDelegates: [
   // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
 ],
 supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('es'), // Spanish
    // ... other locales the app supports
  ],
  // ...
)
```

Comment: you should use LocalizationDelegate: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Comment: After a while I just implemented localisation using intl. Didn't help, any other ideas?